# Only last result being displayed

Tags: php, regex, foreach

I am looking to search multiple websites for a single piece of data. The data is being pulled correctly, however it only displays for the last search case. A single search works fine.

E.g I do three searches, only the third result is displayed - the rest are blank.

Could anyone shed some light?

```
if($_POST)
{

$domains = explode("\n", $_POST[domains]);
foreach($domains as $domain)
{
$domain = explode('|', $domain);
$domain = str_replace(array('http://','/'),'',$domain[0]);

echo '<b>Providing Data for '. $domain .'.. </br></br>';


unset($urls);
unset($url);
unset($blacklinka[1]);
unset($blacklinka);
unset($AskApache_result);
unset($regex);

$domainshort = str_replace('www.','',$domain);

$domainshortdash = str_replace('.','-',$domainshort);


$urls[] = 'http://data.alexa.com/data?cli=10&dat=snbamz&url=' . $domain;




$ch = curl_init();

    foreach($urls as $url)
{

curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US;     rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6");
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://www.google.com/');
    $AskApache_result = curl_exec ($ch);



$regex = '/LINKSIN NUM="(.+?)"/';
preg_match($regex,$AskApache_result,$blacklinka);
echo '</br>';
echo 'Indexed Backlinks: '. $blacklinka[1];

    echo '</br></br>';


    flush();
    ob_flush();
}

}

}
```

Comment: Check the return value of preg_match. Also you're unsetting $urls at the top ...

Comment: Can you give us some more complete code? Where is `$urls` defined?

Comment: I added the complete code, thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

I've tried your code and it works just fine for me. So I have a few ideas as to why it doesn't work for you.

- Since the `foreach($domains as $domain)` loop does `unset($urls)`, if the loop using `$urls` is actually located outside the foreach, then it will only contain the last one.
- You explode `$domains` on `\n` and then `$domain` on `|` which may suggest you have an odd input format, and it may not quite work as you had intended, so looking at `$domains` and `$domain` in your loop might shed some light into what you actually get from your input.

As far as I can tell the curl and preg_match works properly. So either you aren't doing all the curl calls (due to the unset) or your inputted list of domains doesn't get interpreted as you expected.